# Woocommerce Checkout function

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to execute below script while doing checkout in woocommerce.

```
    $args = http_build_query(array(
    'token' => '*********',
    'from'  => '****',
    'to'    => '*******',
    'text'  => 'Your Order Id is: 9879987 '));

$url = "http://api.sparrowsms.com/v2/sms/";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$args);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

I didn't find checkout process page.

Comment: @AdhershMNair I just want to add my sms gateway api. My concept is when user's do checkout in final step i want to send sms with order id.

Comment: You may try `woocommerce_after_checkout_form` hook.

Comment: @AdhershMNair In which php file i can find woocommerce_after_checkout_form ? I'm new in woocommerce.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `woocommerce_after_checkout_form` hook in `function.php` like below.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'sms_function', 10 );

function sms_function( ) {
    $args = http_build_query(array(
    'token' => '*********',
    'from'  => '****',
    'to'    => '*******',
    'text'  => 'Your Order Id is: 9879987 '));

$url = "http://api.sparrowsms.com/v2/sms/";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$args);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
}
```